# What is the default TextStyle for label in TextField in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, textstyle

I want to have the same TextStyle for the DropdownButton hint and items (Text) as that of the label in TextField widget. In my case, the dropdown item is as follows -

```
DropdownMenuItem<String>(
     value: value,
     child: Text(value),
);
// where the value is a String
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the `style` of the `DropDownButton` hint and items to:

```
Theme.of(context).inputDecorationTheme.labelStyle
```

Example:

```
Text(
  'sample text',
  style: Theme.of(context).inputDecorationTheme.labelStyle,
)
```